# How to change body background color within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the challenge portion of the Guess the Colour exercise on the Raspberry Pi site (https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/cd-beginner-javascript-sushi/8).

The challenge asks for me to change body background color to the winning color in the game where you you're presented with an RGB color code at the top and 6 colored circles below that. You have to guess which of the 6 colored circles has the presented RGB color code by clicking on each one, and the program tells you if you're correct and incorrect.

Upon choosing the correct circle, the body background color should change to that of the correct circle, which is where I'm having trouble. I think my code is right, but I think the problem deals with the locality of certain variables and not accounting for that.

The area in question is lines 40-50 in my script.js document; there also some commented out lines that I used to troubleshoot. The document.body.style.backgroundColor line does work, but the function call to setButtonColour and also the setAttribute function do not work.

My code is here at https://trinket.io/html/ad056ed56d?runMode=autorun

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName('body');` returns a list of `<body>` elements.

You should change this line to `var winning = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` to access the first (and only) `<body>` element.

Comment: Adding [0] after ('body') made a difference. Thanks! The body background color does change now, but it's still not quite right, but I'll have to figure out what else is wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to `<body>` in javascript you should use `document.body`.

DOCS:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_body.asp

It looks like there is an error in line 46 in your code:

`winning.setAttribute('style','background-color: rgb('+ red +','+ green +','+ blue +');');`

Look at the end of the line - you shouldn't use `;` after `background-color` right here `+');');`

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Change body color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're generating the colors without saving the right answer.

```
if (i === answerButton) {
  
  heading.innerHTML = 'R:' + red + ' G:' + green + ' B:' + blue;
  //add this ->
  winnerRed = red;
  winnerGreen = green;
  winnerBlue = blue;
}
```

And you call it with this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+ winnerRed +","+ winnerGreen +","+ winnerBlue + ")";
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! The body background color does change now, but it's still not quite right. It's displaying the wrong color now. I think it has to do with how the for loop goes through the colors. I need to tweak something but can't specify it just yet. Thanks again.